# OS X crashed when usb unplug

Tags: macos, crash, adb

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this，thanks very much!

```
 here is my system info:
    OS X EI Capitan 
    version:10.11.6
 android studio version:
    Android Studio 2.2.3
    Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
    JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b05 x86_64
    JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

here is my crash step:

## step 1:open Android Studio;

## step 2:connect Android mobile phone,like this;

[adb connect][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVi7j.png

## step 3:sometimes usb offline like this

[adb disconnected][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3V8W.png

## then unplug the usb,and mac crashed, and get this error message:

```
Anonymous UUID:       5FE85A00-83F5-8F1E-0806-0EEB1FDD7638

Thu Jan 12 14:52:11 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80123bf2fe): Preemption level underflow, possible cause unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff911f5fbc30 : 0xffffff80122d7b92 
0xffffff911f5fbcb0 : 0xffffff80123bf2fe 
0xffffff911f5fbcc0 : 0xffffff80123bf01f 
0xffffff911f5fbcd0 : 0xffffff801288869b 
0xffffff911f5fbd20 : 0xffffff8012892180 
0xffffff911f5fbd70 : 0xffffff80128dc149 
0xffffff911f5fbde0 : 0xffffff8012394b81 
0xffffff911f5fbe30 : 0xffffff80122dc303 
0xffffff911f5fbe60 : 0xffffff80122bf938 
0xffffff911f5fbea0 : 0xffffff80122cf6e5 
0xffffff911f5fbf10 : 0xffffff80123b625a 
0xffffff911f5fbfb0 : 0xffffff80123ea3c6 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: adb

Mac OS version:
15G1212

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Wed Nov  2 20:30:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.11.1.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 865631CA-FB7C-31CA-9B7F-5CBFF3C38E0C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012100000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2002335759820
last loaded kext at 698166579884: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f94e96000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 716207499513: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.1.12 (addr 0xffffff7f94dc4000, size 397312)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.12.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.1.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.46.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 86
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   2.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    43
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  43
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B17, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: MI Wireless Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Same here  :-(   Preemption level underflow

Comment: See also: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231176
Allegedly fixed on platform tools 25.0.2 + Mac 10.12

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I solved this by upgrade the OS X to Sierra,Version:10.12.3